# server side events from external switch

Tags: php, angularjs, arduino, server-sent-events

i am trying to write php code which would broadcast the value of a specific field in a database, whenever another page tells it to.

to give some context, i have a custom timer always open on a page, and i want the user to be able to turn this on via an external hardware switch, which updates the field in a database, and informs the server to broadcast this change, initiating the timer. if possible i would like to forego the middle man in general and have the switch tell the server to broadcast the switch value kick starting the timer.

is what i am proposing possible? I've started using Server Sent Events but havn't got the proper hang of it...

```
 <?php
 header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');

 require "conf/config.php";

  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
         try {  
             $con=mysqli_connect(DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
         } catch (Exception $exp) {
             echo "<label style='font-weight:bold; color:red'>MySQL Server Connection Failed.       </label>";
             exit;
         }

 $query = 'SELECT SwitchPressed FROM live_timers WHERE Timer = 1';

 $result = mysqli($con,$query);
 $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 echo "data: {$data}\n\n";
 flush();
```

And i have this in my controller,

```
 var Events = new EventSource('latch.php');

     Events.onmessage = function(event) {
         console.log(event.data);
     };
```

just testing if stuff works, unfortunately like this i get no messages... thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

In the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) doc, they use a `while` loop that never ends (because it's a stream)